# Kurento recording caller and callee stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, record, webrtc, kurento

I am using kurento to record the stream to the server-disk. I followed the change of the [kurento tutorial here](https://gist.github.com/lulop-k/09b3b05ac9ec341e479c)
where the tutorial hello-world in node.js was changed to record the stream to the disk.
Now what I want to do is change the [tutorial4 one-to-one call](http://www.kurento.org/docs/5.0.3/tutorials/node/tutorial-4-one2one.html) to record the caller and the callee stream to 2 files.

As I understanded kurento the recorder is linked to the pipeline. The pipeline is the representation of the connection between 2 peers. 
How can I record the stream of a single peer in the pipeline, respectively both streams the one of the caller and the one of the callee?

I tried a lot but could not find a sollution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you should be reading the basic [Kurento documentation](http://www.kurento.org/docs/current/introducing_kurento.html#creating-applications-with-kurento) introducing what's a media element and what's a pipeline to have a more clear image on how Kurento's API work.

For you specific question, a RecorerEndpoint is just media element capable of recording to a file the stream offered as its input. This means that you can connect a RecorderEndpoint to any other source element. For example, if you have a B2B call among two peers, every peer will have associated a WebRtcEndpoint so that the resulting pipeline will be something like this:

```
Peer A <--------->webRtcEndpointA<==>webRtcEndpointB<---------->Peer B
```

For recording the streams coming from both Peer A and Peer B, you just need to create two RecorderEndpoints and connect them appropriately so that the final pipeline is something like:

```
                             ------>recorderEndpointA
                             |
 Peer A <--------->webRtcEndpointA<==>webRtcEndpointB<---------->Peer B
                                        |
                                        --->recorderEndpointB
```

The source code for this should include (I ommit the boilerplate code that you already have in the tutorials you cite):

```
pipeline.create('RecorderEndpoint', {uri: "file:///tmp/fileA.webm"}, function(error, recorderEndpointA ...
...
webRtcEndpointA.connect(recorderEndpointA);
recorderEndpointA.record();

pipeline.create('RecorderEndpoint', {uri: "file:///tmp/fileB.webm"}, function(error, recoderEndpointB ...
...
webRtcEndpointB.connect(recorderEndpointB);
recorderEndpointB.record();
```